# Wait for Promise to finish

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I want to run some code, after some other code has run.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {

this.dotheform().then(data => {
        this.updateprovisioncost(data, survey_id, service_id)
})

 dotheform() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      var form = document.querySelector('#configure-form');
      Rails.fire(form, 'submit')
      resolve(true)
    });
  }


updateprovisioncost(data, survey_id, service_id){
    Rails.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: `/provisions/survey_id/${survey_id}/service_id/${service_id}`
   })
  }

}
```

The code does not do what I want, It runs the updateprovisioncost method before the dotheform method has completed.

Comment: how can you tell ?

Comment: Why? Does the code look like it might achive the goal? I had console.log statements in there, also, inspecting rails s logs

Comment: Besides the error that you cannot run the `this.dotheform` directly in the body of the class, the https://codesandbox.io/s/jn5m1n1xxy shows the correct order of things happening. Since you were logging stuff, what was wrong in the order of things ?

Comment: The first ajax call does not complete before the second one is called.  That is the issue.  Need to wait.  I'm simply asking how to wait till it has finished.

Comment: I only see one Ajax call. The `Rails.fire` just triggers a DOM event.

Comment: Which is submitting a form remotely.  I want to wait for that to finish.

Comment: But where is the code that handles the form submission remotely ?

Comment: Its abastracted away in the rails stuff.  I'm getting the impression its not possible to wait for the Rails.fire call to finish?

Comment: I do not think you can directly wait. Unless the code that handles the submission offers a hook to access the Promise.

Comment: Ok, thanks, helpful to hear that anyway, makes working around it feel a bit less hacky.